# Variables in Dockerfile don't seem to be recognized?

Tags: docker, containers, podman

I am building an image using Dockfile. I would like to set the Username of the container via the command line to avoid permission issues.

The Dockfile is shown below, I used the variables of `USER_NAME`, `GROUP_ID`. But when I build, the problem keeps appearing.
The error is: `groupadd: option '--gid' requires an argument`
I'm guessing that both ${GROUP_ID} and ${USER_NAME} are recognized as empty strings, but shouldn't they be assigned values ​​when the container is created?
I've googled a few examples and based on the examples, I don't quite see where the problem is?

Please help me!
Thanks!

```
FROM matthewfeickert/docker-python3-ubuntu:latest
ARG USER_NAME
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID


RUN groupadd -r --gid ${GROUP_ID} ${USER_NAME} 
RUN useradd --no-log-init -r -g ${GROUP_ID} -u ${USER_ID} ${USER_NAME}

USER ${USER_NAME}
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the container, you can specify an arbitrary user ID with the `docker run -u` option.

```bash
docker run -u 1003 ... my-image
```

This doesn't require any special setup in the image.  The user ID won't exist in the container's `/etc/passwd` file but there aren't really any consequences to this, beyond some cosmetic issues with prompts in interactive debugging shells.

A typical use of this is to give your container access to a bind-mounted data directory:

```bash
docker run \
  -e DATA_DIR=/data \
  -v "$PWD/app-data:/data" \
  -u $(id -u) \
  ... \
  my-image
```

I'd generally recommend *not* passing a specific user ID into your image build.  This would make the user ID "baked in", and if someone with a different host uid wanted to run the image, they'd have to rebuild it.

It's often a good practice to set up some non-root user, but it doesn't matter what its user ID is so long as it's not zero.  In turn, it's also typically a good practice to leave most of your application source code owned by the root user so that the application can't accidentally overwrite itself.

```bash
FROM matthewfeickert/docker-python3-ubuntu:latest

# Create an arbitrary non-root user; we don't care about its uid
# or other properties
RUN useradd --system user

# Still as root, do the normal steps to install and build the application
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./

# Still as root, make sure the data directory exists
ENV DATA_DIR=/data
RUN mkdir "$DATA_DIR" && chown user "$DATA_DIR"
# VOLUME ["/data"]

# Normal metadata to run the container, only switching users now
EXPOSE 5000
USER user
CMD ["./app.py"]
```

This setup will still work with the extended `docker run` command shown initially: the `docker run -v` option will cause the container's `/data` directory to take on its numeric uid owner from the host, which (hopefully) matches the `docker run -u` uid.

Comment: I found that if I follow the above way, create a User user. When I mount a file into the container, the mounted file is still only accessible by root. If I specify the UID, the specified user and the User user defined in the Dockerfile are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the build args as shown below.

```
docker build --build-arg USER_NAME=test --build-arg USER_ID=805 --build-arg GROUP_ID=805 -t tag1 .
```

Also, as a best practice consider adding default vales to the args. So if the user doesn't specify the args the default values will be picked.

Comment: Thanks! 
I thought it was necessary to set parameters when creating a container, but it turned out to be required when creating an image.